# MySQL Grouping rows by a shared ID

Tags: mysql

Say I have

```
ID | PRODUCT
 1 |  Apples
 1 | Oranges
 1 | Bananas
 2 | Walnuts
 2 | Almonds
 3 | Steak
 3 | Chicken
```

Is this possible to have this type of setup in MySQL? I created a test table, and made an ID column with primary index and auto incrementing. When I try to insert a couple rows all having the same ID, mysql returns an error.

Is this possible to do in mysql?

Comment: That's the entire point of a primary key. It _must_ be unique by definition. If you need non-unique `ID`, don't define it as the PK.  Sounds like you just want `CREATE TABLE products (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL, PRODUCT VARCHAR());`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski is totally right. I would, instead, not touch the id column but instead create a new one for this matter, or rename this default to something like **uid** and create a secondary (non PK) with the name **id**.

Answer (score 1):

How did the duplicate records (*ID*) `INSERTED` when you set `ID` as Primary Key? Basically, it will not. Primary Keys are `UNIQUE`. If you want records to be like that, make another column which served as your primary key

```
CREATE TABLE sampleTable
(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    GROUP_ID INT NOT NULL, 
    PRODUCT VARCHAR(25),
    CONSTRAINT pk_name PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT uq_name UNIQUE (GROUP_ID, PRODUCT)
)
```

a `UNIQUE` constraint was added so to avoid duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0):

That is possible, but it is not normalized as you have a repeating primary key. Primary keys must be unique, which means `1` can only occur once. If you have custom `ID`'s for each `product`, then either use a compound primary key `(id, product)` or a surrogate key. A surrogate key would be an auto incrementing column that uniquely identifies the row. Your table would then look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE fruits (
  auto_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id int,
  product varchar(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't create a primary key for the ID column, as this implies that it's unique.
Just take a normal index for your example.

On the other hand, in most cases, it makes sense to have a primary key, so I'd recommend adding a 3rd row (GENRE?) with a normal INDEX on it and leaving the primary key as it is.

When inserting data, just insert the GENRE and the PRODUCT, the ID will be automatically filled.